# Stacking info I on another div

Tags: html, css

Wrapping my brain on this one...

On our checkout page we have some payment options. With two of those options i've added an information i and when you hover this there will come a container with some information.

But this container falls behind the other text.

[image: picatuh]

I have added a z-index but the problem still exists.

Some code:

```css
.infoI:hover .infoContainer {
        display: block !important;
        position: absolute;
        background: #eee;
        width: 185px;
        z-index: 999 !important;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .infoI {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .infoContainer {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div data-method="true" class="gui-payment-method gui-payment-method-service gui-is-selected">
 <label for="gui-payment-paynl-1987" class="gui-clearfix active">
  <input class="gui-left" id="gui-payment-paynl-1987" type="radio" name="payment_method" data-provider="paynl" data-method="1987" value="paynl|1987" checked="checked">
  <img class="gui-payment-method-icon" src="https://www.pay.nl/images/payment_profiles/50x32/1987.png" height="32" alt="SprayPay (in 12-36 maanden)">
  <span class="gui-payment-method-subtitle">
   <span class="gui-payment-method-price gui-right">
    Gratis
   </span>
   <span class="gui-payment-method-name sprayPayInfo">SprayPay (in 12-36 maanden)<div class="infoI"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><div class="infoContainer">Bij de keuze voor SprayPay betaal je je bestelling (mogelijk tussen € 250,- en € 2500,-) in 12 maandelijkse gelijke termijnen. De definitieve acceptatie van de financiering is voorbehouden aan SprayPay. SprayPay hanteert een rentepercentage van 14%. Wil je zelf berekenen hoeveel je per maand moet betalen? Gebruik dan de rekenformule:  Aankoopbedrag x 0,08940 = maandbedrag voor 12 maanden.</div></div></span>
  </span>
 </label>
</div>
```

Styling from: span.gui-payment-method-price.gui-right

```
.gui-checkout-one-step .gui-payment-methods .gui-payment-method .gui-right {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 2px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try giving negative z-index to the .gui-payment-method-price? I mean z-index: -1?

Comment: Tried that but still no luck

Comment: With the above code we can't capture the issue. Can you give the code-styles for Gratis ?

Comment: i've edited the question and placed the styling of .gui-checkout-one-step .gui-payment-methods .gui-payment-method .gui-right

Comment: @Ger sorry but i still can't capture the issue.

Comment: Solved in another way by completely changing the html structure!